# How to start a subprogram and write a command to it with python 3

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, popen

This code starts Notepad but do not write into it...

```
import subprocess

self.process = subprocess.Popen('C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe',
                                 shell=True, 
                                 stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                                 cwd=None,
                                 env=None)

self.process.stdin.write('Hi\n'.encode())
```

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.  [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is your final goal to have a file saved with the content provided by the python subprocess or are you aiming to open the notepad and "live update" it with the content provided by the subprocess (I'm not sure this one is possible).

Comment: @LucasInfante Looks like that is what he is trying to do.   This will not work.  Stdin will not feed data to the windows event loop that results in data appearing in notepad.  This would require a package that can directly manipulate App windows in Windows.